# vertical scrollbar with border layout in the south region

Tags: layout, extjs, scrollbar

With extjs i have a south region with a panel in there. The problem is that when you resize the south area there is no scrollbar in the panel.

This is the south area

```
var southDetails = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        region: 'south',
        animCollapse: false,
        title: 'South Region',
        height: 300,
        stateful: true,
        loadMask: false,
        collapsible: true,
        floatable: false,
        collapsed: true,
        hideCollapseTool: true,
        split: true,
        stateId: 'stateSouthDetails',
        items: [ test   ]
 });
```

And the item i use here is test. This is because i want to get the scrollbar in there.

```
var test = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            autoscroll: true,
        height: 300,
        stateful: true,
            stateId: 'stateTestDetails',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
        autoscroll: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            title: 'Test Panel'
        }]
 })
```

I can see that the panel is 300 height. But there is no scrollbar when i resize the southpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define height, minsize and maxsize within the panel (south). take a look at this working example (EXTJS 4.0). if you collapse the south region, there will be appear a scrollbar within the south region. try it :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4.0.2a/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.2a/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var test = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            title: 'Testpanel',
            region: 'center',
            html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   '
    });




    Ext.require(['*']);
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            layout: {
                type: 'border'
            },
            defaults: {
                collapsible: true,
                split: true,
                autoScroll: true
            },
            items: [{
                region: 'center',
                title: 'Center',
                html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
            },{
                region: 'south',
                title: 'South',
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: false,
                split: true,
                height: 175,
                minSize: 150,
                maxSize: 300,
                items: [test]
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```